# Should I update blog posts or rewrite them as technology (and me) changes?

Tags: communication

I started a programming blog earlier this year, and since I started it some things have changed. Some changes are due to technology changing, some changes are due to my code libraries improving, and some (ok, probably most) are due to me changing as I learn more.

I want to go back and completely re-write certain blog posts. Is it better to rewrite posts to remove old information and update them with new stuff, or to create entirely new posts and possibly take down old ones?

I'm not talking about small changes to the code, or an extra few sentences, but complete rewrites with new code, new information, etc.

Some things to consider are comments on the post, subscribers who receive updates when new posts are created, and user bookmarks.

Comment: Keep the old blog posts as they are.  Obligatory XKCD link sums up the reasons why: http://www.xkcd.com/979/

Comment: If they are still frequently visited you could add a short notice how things changed or offer a link to a newer version.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the best approach is to leave the old entries/code samples where they are, and to add new ones with your new ideas/code samples. Then you can include a link on the older posts pointing to the new ones.

This approach allows both you and your visitors to see how your code/ideas evolved over time, which could be valuable. And there's nothing wrong with admitting the stuff you did/wrote a while ago was not as good as it could have been. The very fact that you are recognizing that is a sign of your progress.

Comment: +1, I would say that it's also OK (and in some cases, maybe strongly recommended) to add a small note at the top of the old post saying "Newer ideas on this topic are here: [link]". Cross-referencing links could make it easier to trace the development of the idea.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, agreed.

Comment: And, from a purely mercenary point of view, you'll get more page hits from people reading both posts.

Comment: It's definitely a good idea to put the note at the *top*, so that any traffic from search engines can be quickly directed to a good current answer before they decide the content is old and leave. (If they really are looking for old things, they'll quickly skim past it.)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go this route. Over time if my old stuff doesn't get very many views, I'll just take it down. I feel some of my older stuff is badly written, and could use a rewrite with some cleaner code examples.

Answer (score 4):

I personaly dont like deleting old posts, information even if not up to date is still often usefull. Some people may for example be using the outdated librarys. Also some of the comments may be usefull in ways that are not immediately obvious

In my opinion the best to deal with this situation is to write a new post and clearly mark the new post as superseded with a link to the updated post at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably those old post are very valuable stuff to those who working on old frameworks/ technologies,  So I suggest you to keep them on your blog. Even they will represent your skills and valuable idea behind them which also let some to use your ideas.

That what you can do is  that create new post by tagging the updated technology version and older version on older post.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend keeping the info as is. My VB.NET blog hasn't been updated since 2007 and it sees a good amount of traffic from people looking for older stuff, typically 500-700 unique visitors a day. My really old (circa 1999) VB6 static HTML pages even get a bit of traffic.

You can go back and edit posts to add links to newer posts. In some cases, I've added a bold Update header that explains why I don't recommend something anymore.